# Sorting the XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Input XML:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:Username>User</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>Password</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <soap-env:CustomerRs>
            <Information>
                <Identity Code="DFW">
                    <User LoginID="123456" />
                </Identity>
                <User>
                    <Customer Gender="Male">
                        <Person>
                            <GivenName>Tester2</GivenName>
                            <LastName>Tester</LastName>
                        </Person>
                        <Telephone Type="Business" InfoNo="1" SeqNo="1">
                            <Number Area="456" Phone="7878787" />
                        </Telephone>
                        <Info InfoNo="2" SeqNo="1">
                            <LastName>Wilson</LastName>
                            <GivenName>Kelley</GivenName>
                        </Info>
                        <Info InfoNo="4" SeqNo="1">
                            <LastName>Graham</LastName>
                            <GivenName>Tom</GivenName>
                        </Info>
                        <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="3">
                            <LastName>Fisher</LastName>
                            <GivenName>Elaine</GivenName>
                        </Info>
                        <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="2">
                            <LastName>Gary</LastName>
                            <GivenName>Jerry</GivenName>
                        </Info>
                        <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="1">
                            <LastName>Timothy</LastName>
                            <GivenName>Kathy</GivenName>
                        </Info>
                        <Info InfoNo="3" SeqNo="1">
                            <LastName>Tim</LastName>
                            <GivenName>Kerry</GivenName>
                        </Info>
                        <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="4">
                            <LastName>Rob</LastName>
                            <GivenName>Tony</GivenName>
                        </Info>
                        <Address Type="Business" InfoNo="1" SeqNo="1">
                            <Line1>Menands Ln</Line1>
                            <City>Albany</City>
                        </Address>
                    </Customer>
                    <Order type="S">
                        <Ref>ABC123</Ref>
                        <OrderedBy>
                            <Debtor code="BLABLA"></Debtor>
                        </OrderedBy>
                        <DeliveryMethod code="Barefoot"></DeliveryMethod>
                        <OrderLine line="1">
                            <Item code="QQQ123456"></Item>
                            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        </OrderLine>
                    </Order>
                </User>
            </Information>
        </soap-env:CustomerRs>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Expected Output XML Response:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:Username>User</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>Password</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <soap-env:CustomerRs>
            <Information>
                <Identity Code="DFW">
                    <User LoginID="123456" />
                </Identity>
                <User>
                    <Customer Gender="Male">
                        <Person>
                            <GivenName>Tester2</GivenName>
                            <LastName>Tester</LastName>
                        </Person>
                        <Telephone Type="Business" InfoNo="1" SeqNo="1">
                            <Number Area="456" Phone="7878787" />
                        </Telephone>
                        <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="1">
                            <LastName>Timothy</LastName>
                            <GivenName>Kathy</GivenName>
                        </Info>
                        <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="2">
                            <LastName>Gary</LastName>
                            <GivenName>Jerry</GivenName>
                        </Info>
                        <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="3">
                            <LastName>Fisher</LastName>
                            <GivenName>Elaine</GivenName>
                        </Info>
                        <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="4">
                            <LastName>Rob</LastName>
                            <GivenName>Tony</GivenName>
                        </Info>
                        <Info InfoNo="2" SeqNo="1">
                            <LastName>Wilson</LastName>
                            <GivenName>Kelley</GivenName>
                        </Info>
                        <Info InfoNo="3" SeqNo="1">
                            <LastName>Tim</LastName>
                            <GivenName>Kerry</GivenName>
                        </Info>
                        <Info InfoNo="4" SeqNo="1">
                            <LastName>Graham</LastName>
                            <GivenName>Tom</GivenName>
                        </Info>
                        <Address Type="Business" InfoNo="1" SeqNo="1">
                            <Line1>Menands Ln</Line1>
                            <City>Albany</City>
                        </Address>
                    </Customer>
                    <Order type="S">
                        <Ref>ABC123</Ref>
                        <OrderedBy>
                            <Debtor code="BLABLA"></Debtor>
                        </OrderedBy>
                        <DeliveryMethod code="Barefoot"></DeliveryMethod>
                        <OrderLine line="1">
                            <Item code="QQQ123456"></Item>
                            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        </OrderLine>
                    </Order>
                </User>
            </Information>
        </soap-env:CustomerRs>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

My xslt that is doing transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='Envelope']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:sort select="/*[local-name()='Info']/@*[local-name()='InfoNo']" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
                <xsl:sort select="/*[local-name()='Info']/@*[local-name()='SeqNo']" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I used this stylesheet to sort and arrange but still producing the same input as is. What exactly I'm doing wrong, I'm not able to get the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following adjustment. For sorting, no need to walk down the entire tree since you use the identity template to copy document as is. Simply add a template for the sorting section, namely the parent tag, here being `<Customer>` and then sort only its `<Info>` children.

Also, *InfoNo* and *SeqNo* are attributes so should be referenced with `@`. Finally, as best practice try adding `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` at top of XSLT to strip out whitespace text nodes which adds a bit of efficiency since such nodes are stripped out from memory.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Customer">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Person|Telephone"/>            
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Info">
                <xsl:sort select="@InfoNo" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
                <xsl:sort select="@SeqNo" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Address"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about the difference between relative paths and absolute paths. To compute a sort key for an element E, you will (almost) always want to select some value using a path that starts at E, that is, a relative path. A path that starts with "/" is an absolute path, which starts at the top of the document, and therefore computes the same value regardless of where E is. So a sort key computed using an absolute path, like `<xsl:sort select="/*[.....]"/>`, has to be wrong.